# SQL: Find a record joined to a single table where same column has different values

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause, having-clause

I have a table called `entities` that has many associated `records` which in turn have `names` and `values` (2 more tables).

I need to find a record in `entities` table that has two associated records with the following conditions:

- one with name "Name 1` and value "Value 1"
- second one with name "Name 2" and value "Value 2"

For now I have such invalid SQL:

```
SELECT entities.id
FROM   `entities`
       INNER JOIN `records`
               ON `records`.`entity_id` = `entities`.`id`
       INNER JOIN `names`
               ON `names`.`id` = `records`.`name_id`
       INNER JOIN `values`
               ON `values`.`record_id` =`records`.`id`
WHERE  
           `names`.`name` = 'Name 1'
       AND `names`.`resource_type` = 'Type'
       AND ( values.value LIKE '%Value 1%' )
       AND `names`.`name` = 'Name 2'
       AND `names`.`resource_type` = 'Type'
       AND ( values.value LIKE '%Value 2%' )
```

This SQL has mutually exclusive conditions and in result it returns nothing. So the question is how to produce a valid SQL to retrieve required records?

Comment: You have two conditions on name.name, which are by the way they are configured, will always produce a zero row result set. Is your intention to get two names from name by some join? if so, you will need a second join to the table on a different criteria to get the second name.

Comment: My query was just an idea and yeah, it doesn't work. I need to find en entity that has record with associated name = Name 1 and values.value = Value 1 and one more record with associated name = Name 2 and values.value = Value 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query returns no rows because you have conflicting conditions in the `WHERE` clause. If I am following this correctly, you can aggregate and filter with a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT e.id
FROM entities e
INNER JOIN records r ON r.entity_id = e.id
INNER JOIN names n   ON n.id = r.name_id
INNER JOIN values v  ON v.record_id =r.id
WHERE n.resource_type = 'Type'
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING MAX(n.name = 'Name 1' AND v.value LIKE '%Value 1%') = 1
   AND MAX(n.name = 'Name 2' AND v.value LIKE '%Value 2%') = 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need @GMB! Thanks a lot, it works

Comment: The only question is why do we use `MAX` with boolean result (the conditions)? @GMB